# Adding JPanel from one class to a JPanel in a different class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have frame JFrame to which I'm adding gui JPanel which consists of multiple different JPanels and one of which is in a different class.

The problem is I'm unable to add that other classes JPanel to my gui JPanel I get no errors but nothing is displayed

**PurchaseStock.java**

```
    guiC.gridx=0;
    guiC.gridy=0;
    gui.add(StockDropdown.getP(), guiC);

    guiC.gridx=1;
    guiC.gridy=0;
    gui.add(quantityP, guiC);

    guiC.insets = new Insets(30,0,0,0);
    guiC.gridwidth=2;
    guiC.gridx=0;
    guiC.gridy=1;
    gui.add(checkout, guiC);

    frame.add(gui);
    frame.pack(); //Size to components

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

**StackDropdown.java**

```
public class StockDropdown {

    private static JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JButton bt = new JButton("tsfdsfds");
    private JPanel top = new JPanel();
    private JPanel middle = new JPanel();


    public StockDropdown(){
       ui.add("North", top);
       top.add(bt);
    }
    public static JPanel getP(){
        return ui;
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

**PurchaseStock.java**

```
public class PurchaseStock extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints guiC = new GridBagConstraints();

    public PurchaseStock(){
        frame.setTitle("Update Stock");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


        guiC.gridx=0;
        guiC.gridy=0;
        gui.add(new StockDropdown(), guiC);


        frame.add(gui);
        frame.pack(); //Size to components

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }


}
```

**StackDropdown.java**

```
package stock;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StockDropdown extends JPanel{

    private JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JButton bt = new JButton("tsfdsfds");
    private JPanel top = new JPanel();
    private JPanel middle = new JPanel();


    public StockDropdown(){

       ui.add("North", top);
       top.add(bt);

    }


}
```

Update 2:

**StockDropdown.java**

```
package stock;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StockDropdown extends JPanel{
    private JComboBox itemsDropdown = new JComboBox();

    private JPanel top = new JPanel();
    private JPanel middle = new JPanel();
    JButton t = new JButton("tt");

    public StockDropdown(){

       add("North", top);
       add("Center", middle);
       top.add(itemsDropdown);

       for(String key : StockData.getStock().keySet())  {
         itemsDropdown.addItem(StockData.getName(key));
       }
       middle.add(t);

    }

     private ImageIcon setImageSize(String path) {
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(path);
        Image image2 = image1.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,0);
        return new ImageIcon(image2);
    };

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do get the other JPanel but you've added nothing to it since components are added in its constructor and the StockDropdown constructor is never called. I'd get rid of the static fields and methods unless you plan to create a true valid static factory method, one that calls the appropriate constructor.

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class StockDropdown extends JPanel {
    private JButton bt = new JButton("tsfdsfds");
    private JPanel top = new JPanel();
    private JPanel middle = new JPanel();

    // make this private if using factory method
    private StockDropdown(){
       add("North", top);
       top.add(bt);
    }

    // public static factory method
    public static StockDropdown getInstance() {
        StockDropdown ui = new StockDropdown();
        return ui;
    }
}
```

Note that if StockDropdown extends JPanel, get rid of the ui variable, because with it, you're adding components to a container that is not being displayed:

```
public class StockDropdown extends JPanel {
    private JButton bt = new JButton("tsfdsfds");
    private JPanel top = new JPanel();
    private JPanel middle = new JPanel();

    public StockDropdown() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        top.add(bt);
        // add("North", top);
        add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I somehow put all of that just in the constructor? So then I could call gui.add(new StockDropdown())?

Comment: @Higeath: yep, and that's the route I'd take, **if** StockDropdown extended JPanel. If not you'd need `gui.add(new StockDropdown().getUi());` and make ui an instance field.

Comment: so that what i did added extend JPanel changed to gui.add (new StockDropdown());    public StockDropdown(){
      
       ui.add("North", top);
       top.add(bt);} no errors what so ever but still I can't see the button

Comment: @Higeath: please edit your original question. Leave the original code in place, but at the bottom please add your new formatted code, and let's see what you're doing. Best if you could create and post a [mcve].

Comment: @Higeath: get rid of the `ui` variable then. Wait for edit to answer.

Comment: I have one more question if you wouldn't mind I've added   add("Center", middle); and added random button to middle and it shows up to the right of the top button not below him for some reason same if I change Center to South

Comment: @Higeath: 1) are you setting the layout to BorderLayout as I show above? 2) show pertinent code in your question, and avoid using Strings for your BorderLayout constraints -- use the constants, again as I show above.

Comment: I've added update 2 with code and nothing changed in purchasestock.java

Comment: @Higeath: because you're 1) still using String constants -- don't, and most important, 2) not using BorderLayout in the component that matters.